# Is it possible to use the Active Record paradigm while controlling connections/transactions with QueryRunner?

Tags: typeorm

Currently, I have several TypeORM + TypeGraphQL APIs that we've gotten into production, but as I've gone back and refactored, I was curious if I could adopt more Active Record style db interaction in my mutations without changing the fact that I do all my db operations on a QueryRunner allocated from the pool?

I allocate an exclusive connection from the pool using a QueryRunner for each request context as per the documentation here: https://typeorm.io/query-runner#using-queryrunner and attempt to ensure all reads and writes go through that query runner to ensure that queries stay on that pool connection (some session variables get set up upon context creation) and to make transaction management easier.

Because of this, a lot of our mutation code looks like:

```js
const userEntity = await ctx.queryRunner.manager.findOneOrFail(User, { where: { id: input.id } })

const newEntity = new UserPushSubscription({
    userAccountId: userEntity.id,
    <more data for the new object>
})

await ctx.queryRunner.manager.save(newEntity)
```

This works, and the reads and writes all happen on the same connection, and the data mapper syntax works ok for us for controlling the transaction, but whenever I bring on junior devs, they see the active record syntax and will write `newSub.save()` which could introduce subtle bugs by allocating a second pool connection without session variable set up.

The documentation suggests that both Active Record and Data Mapper syntax are both valid, but I don't see anywhere in the QueryRunner documentation that notes how it could be used with active record.  Is this because its impossible, or is there a way I'm missing.

I did recently find the EntityManager.create endpoint.  It doesn't say in the docs, but reading the js, it looks like the entity it creates is attached to the repository it was created from, so I was curious if at least I can simplify the above example to be something like:

```js
const userEntity = await ctx.queryRunner.manager.findOneOrFail(User, { where: { id: input.id } })

const newEntity = ctx.queryRunner.manager.create(UserPushSubscription, {
    userAccountId: userEntity.id,
    <more data for the new object>
})

await newEntity.save()
```

That is slightly more active-recordy, but now its mixed which seems maybe even worse?  Anyway, I'm just curious if AR and QueryRunner are compatible, and if so, how can I write a mutation that would load some entities, and then save a couple all on an allocated queryrunner?

If not, should the documentation be updated here https://typeorm.io/active-record-data-mapper or here https://typeorm.io/query-runner#working-with-query-runner to say so.

Maybe I'm missing something more global that would make the repositories or data sources be per queryrunner?  Right now, all my entities extend BaseEntity and I generally call `MyEntity.useDataSource(<a globally declared and instantiated data source>)` and maybe I should instead be doing something per request in node?  I'm worried that would complicate importing the classes into the resolvers since I'd probably need to import them and then initialize them somehow, but I'm still curious.